Multiple file uploads resulting in each disabled button becoming enabled
On a page I have multiple file uploads and each has its own Upload button.
When i call the type="submit" button each file load goes off to its own controller and its file is loaded. This works nicely and the same code can be used for all file uploads        $("form").submit(function (eventObj)
What i am struggling with is this: I don't want the user to be able to press the Upload button if they have not selected a file, so i have disabled the button until a file is pressed, the disabling bit works fine. What i need help with is how when the file is selected do i call something that changes the disabled button to enabled (when user selects a file) and works for multiple file uploads using the same bit of code that can be used for all file uploads.
Is there a way to get the enable button to work a bit like this line:             $("form").submit(function (eventObj) {  which handles all file uploads?
I want to try to avoid having different bits of code for each file upload and keeping names like id="filename" the same for every file upload. I can get it working for a single file upload but not multiple.
Hopefully my question makes sense, I am newish to Javascript.


filename.onchange = function(eventObj) {
  //this works but only for the first file upload not the other ones.
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $("#uploadButton").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $("#uploadButton").prop("disabled", true);
  }
};

$("form").submit(function(eventObj) {
  //some stuff
  var formData = new FormData(eventObj.currentTarget);

  $.ajax({
    url: eventObj.currentTarget.action,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("in success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
  });
  return false;
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Upload Files</h1>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFile" asp-controller="Ls" method="post">
  <dl>
    <dd>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="filename">

    </dd>
  </dl>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" id="uploadButton" type="submit" value="Upload" disabled/>
</form>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFile" asp-controller="Cv" method="post">
  <dl>
    <dd>
      <input name="file" type="file" id="filename">
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" id="uploadButton" type="submit" value="Upload" disabled/>
</form>
//there are more of these upload forms




Delegate: $('form').on('change','[name=file]',function() { $(this).closest('form').find('[type=submit]').prop('disabled',this.value==='') - also ID needs to be unique in a page if you want to use it.

When handling the onchange event, you need to navigate your way from the affected file input element to the relevant button.
For example:
$(this).closest("form").children(".uploadButton").prop("disabled", false);

Also, note that the id attribute of an element needs to be unique within the HTML document, so in order for this to work with multiple form, you want to use class attribute of the button.
